# OpenCV - How can I calculate Riemann Distance using C++?

Tags: matlab, opencv, image-processing, distance

The Riemann distance calculation for two covariance matrices A and B in Matlab is:

```
C = sqrt(sum(log(eig(A,B)).^2))
```

What is the equivalent for OpenCV with C++?

Comment: All necessary methods are exists in Opencv see http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html , so what did you try ?

Comment: My main difficult is to calculate the generalized eigenvalues from two covariance matrixes (eig(A,B)) in OpenCV.

Comment: Ok, this may help you: http://www.developerstation.org/2012/04/general-eigen-values-and-eigen-vectors.html

Comment: But seems there should be https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/classEigen_1_1GeneralizedEigenSolver.html instead of https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1EigenSolver.html

Comment: @AndreySmorodov really thank you about your tip. Now I got the same generalized eigenvalues  than Matlab.

Answer (score 2):

Now I got the same results than Matlab. Follows my C++ solution:

```
double calculateRiemannianDistance(cv::Mat A, cv::Mat B) {
Eigen::MatrixXf e_A, e_B;
cv::cv2eigen(A, e_A);
cv::cv2eigen(B, e_B);

/* compute generalized eigenvalues */
Eigen::GeneralizedEigenSolver<Eigen::MatrixXf> ges;
ges.compute(e_A, e_B);
cv::Mat gev;
cv::eigen2cv(Eigen::MatrixXf(ges.eigenvalues().real()), gev);

/* riemannian distance */
cv::Mat partial_res;
cv::log(gev, partial_res);
cv::pow(partial_res, 2, partial_res);
double distance = sqrt(cv::sum(partial_res)[0]);
return distance;
}
```

Comment: @JeruLuke, I used the Riemannian Distance to calculate the distance between two different covariance matrices, since they does not belong to Euclidean space.

Comment: So it is useful for statistical inferences... right?

Comment: I'm not sure about that, @JeruLuke. Sorry.